# Counterexample for L'Hopital's Rule

Tags: analysis, derivatives

In Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (Chp. 5), he states L'Hopital's rule as the following (I'm writing this from memory, so apologies if there are any mistakes):

Given two functions $f, g: (a, b) \to \Bbb{R}$ which are differentiable on $(a, b)$ and with $g'(x) \neq 0$   $\forall x \in (a, b)$.

If $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = A$ and either $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x) = 0$, or $\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x) = \pm \infty$.

Then $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = A$.

My question is: Is there a counterexample which shows that this can't be true if $g'(x) = 0$ for some $x$ in the interval? If there is just one such $x$, then I see that we could shorten the interval to exclude that $x$ and then apply the rule. But is there an example of functions $f, g$ where $\forall c, \exists x \in (a, c)$ such that $g'(x) = 0$, and we cannot apply the rule?

Comment: Acording to Rudin's conventions $\lim_{x \to a}\frac {f'(x)} {g'(x)}$ does not even make sense unless $g'(x)$ has no zero in $(a,a+r)$ for some $r>0$.

Comment: @Chris Eagle Yes, that question is what I was looking for. I understand that strictly speaking the limit of the ratio of derivatives doesn’t exist on $(a,b)$ as $x \to a$ if $x$ is a limit point of the zeros of $g’(x)$, but I was still confused why the rule doesn’t apply if the discontinuities are removable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well obviously no because if $g'(x)$ is zero so many times then the term $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ is not even defined.

I will answer a different question, which I believe is what you really wanted to ask: Does there exists a function $G$ satisfying that for every $c>0$ there exists $x\in (0,c)$ with $G'(x)=0$? The answer is YES.

Lemma: There exists a function $G$ with $$G'(x) = \begin{cases} \sin(\frac{1}{x}) & x\not =0 \\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$$

Proof: Look at $H(x) = \begin{cases} x\cdot \sin(\frac{1}{x}) & x\not =0 \\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$ then
$$H'(x) = \begin{cases} \sin(\frac{1}{x})+x\cdot cos(\frac{1}{x}) & x\not =0 \\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$$

Now the map
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x\cdot cos(\frac{1}{x}) & x\not =0 \\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$$ is continuous, and therefore by the fundamental theorem of the calculus, there exists a function $F$ such that $F'(x)=f(x)$ (I do not know if there is a nice way to write $F$ but you can take $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$).

Let $G(x) = H(x) - F(x)$, then by construction $G'(x) = g(x)$. This completes the proof.

Comment: $H$ itself is an example. It's differentiable on $(0,c)$ and no matter how small $c$ is, $H$ crosses the $x$ axis at least twice in $(0,c).$ By Rolle's Theorem (or MVT) you have that $H'(x)=0$ for some $x$ between those two crossings, which is an $x$ in $(0,c).$